# get element from inside webview javascript chrome app

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app

I've been searching on google for a while now and I couldn't really find much regarding this topic so I wanted to know if it's even possible:

> Can I get an html element from a loaded page inside a `<webview>` and
>   store it's attributes for later use outside of my `<webview>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [webview.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-executeScript) along with [postMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#property-contentWindow) to communicate the data back out of the webview